# How to list files from s3 bucket ending in particular file format?

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I have some files stored in an s3 bucket in the form `s3://unit/by-id/M1/101/M13456/logs/*/data.json`

Is there a way to pull only the `data.json` files using the Java s3 client?

Answer (score 0):

S3 supports prefix based pull only. It doesn't have an api to list or get object data based on *data.json (suffix).